# Secret sharing scheme which cannot tell fake shares from real ones

Tags: secret-sharing

I am looking for a secret sharing algorithm which accepts a large array, some elements of which are real shares and the rest are fake. The algorithm should satisfy the following conditions:

1. If all the real secret shares are present in the array (in whatever places, in whatever order), then the result of the algorithm is the real secret.
2. If ANY ONE of the secret shares is not present within the array, the result of the algorithm is something random-looking. It does not communicate any information about which shares were present, or how many, or where they were in the array.
3. There should be no (computationally feasible) way for an attacker to determine how many real secret shares a given array contains, *unless he already has an array containing all of them*.

---

An example of what the third condition does:

Suppose I have two random-looking arrays. One of them contains 9 out of 10 secret shares mixed in with a few thousand random numbers. The other is just random, with no relation to the secret. But I do not know which array is which.

If I knew the 10th share (or at least, if I had another array which contains the 10th share somewhere in it), I could append it to both arrays and run the algorithm on them. If I have some means of recognizing the real secret when I see it (maybe its hash or something), that would allow me to tell apart the two arrays.

What I'm looking for is an algorithm for which, without having the 10th share, I cannot feasibly distinguish these two arrays.

---

If that kind of algorithm exists, then here's the important consequence: there can be a whole crowd of people *pretending* to be secret holders, and I can try to recover the secret by collecting numbers from the whole crowd, and *unless I succeed* (i.e. unless all the secret holders really are among the crowd and decide to reveal their real shares), I will learn nothing about who the real secret holders are.

Unfortunately, I do not know whether such an algorithm has been researched, and if so, what is this requirement called. A google search for "fake shares" seems to only return algorithms for *detecting* them, which is the exact opposite of what I want.

This may be related to ring signature algorithms (knowing that the secret holder is among a group of people), but I don't know how to adapt ring signatures to this problem.

Comment: Interesting question! Your hard-core requirements of secret sharing(SS) is that real sharings are shuffled with fake ones while keeping the secret can be recovered correctly after filtering the fake ones. However, I think your question's hard point is that it is difficult to distinguish real secret sharings from the fake secret sharings without giving some auxiliary information to the reconstructor. Therefore, the ability of  simulatedly generating fake sharings is needed for the honest in this case, and the honest and the reconstructor must agree on the method of filtering the fake.

Comment: Some methods I guess will give you some inspriation are designed-verifiers technology, re-encryption, or zero-knowledge proof.

Comment: When you say "If I have some means of recognizing the real secret when I see it" ... it makes me think you should secret-share a key, and then use that key to encrypt a [honey encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honey_encryption) of the secret.

Comment: Actually, any reasonable $n$-out-of-$n$ secret sharing scheme has the property you want -- The joint distribution of any subset of $n-1$ shares **is** the uniform distribution.

Comment: @Mikero it doesn't - you can't tell the real shares, so you couldn't recover it from the array

Comment: Error correcting codes might be relevant

Comment: @mingalex I am not against the idea of having some additional **public** information that helps the reconstructor. In fact, I think that is absolutely needed, because the reconstructor needs a unique identifier of THE secret he's looking for (in case the array accidentally contains valid shares of other secrets).

Comment: However, the special requirement I am looking for is that the association between this public identifier and the shares should only become apparent *when I have all of them*, and not a moment earlier.

Comment: OK, I misunderstood the requirement that even the reconstruction algorithm gets a bunch of meaningless dummy shares, but it still expected to recover the secret. This is indeed very difficult.